# MAC OS X Server, process keep respawning after unloaded from launchd

Tags: mac-osx, launchd, launchctl

I am constantly getting the following messages in system log:

> com.apple.launchd.peruser.0 (homebrew.mxcl.memcached[PID]) Exited with code : 64 com.apple.launchd.peruser.0 (homebrew.mxcl.memcached)
>   Throttling respawn: Will start in 10 seconds.

Apparently I have previously loaded the homebrew.mxcl.memcached.plist into launchd to have it run memcached at startup.

After searching online I learned that it is caused by the process failing to start. And a solution is to unload the plist from launchd with `launchctl unload -w /Library/LaunchAgents/homebrew.mxcl.memcached.plist`, and `launchctl remove homebrew.mxcl.memcached`, which I have done.

Note that the peruser.0 in the messages indicates that it is running 'peruser' for the user root. And I am logged in as root user to unload the homebrew.mxcl.memcached entries and remove the labels in launchd.

This worked on another machine to stop the messages(for none root user), but I am still getting the constant respawn messages on this server.

I have confirmed with `launchctl list` that memcached is no longer there and I am getting the intended error messages as well when try to unload/remove memcached in launchctl too. I also get the following when I do `launchctl stop homebrew.mxcl.memcached`

> launchctl stop error: No such process

It looks like the memcached plist was successfully deleted from launchctl.

I am confused on why I am still getting respawn error messages every 10 sec even though the plist is no longer loaded in launchd. I have searched for existing posts in regards to this issue but have found none.

Any help/hints would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

**UPDATE**

I have logged out of the root user and logged in as a normal user to check the log, and the message stops. It looks like the process is still loaded for the root user to run at log in somehow..

Comment: Oh wow, amazing insight!
`launchctl list` will display different results for local user and root.